# adding line breaks in code box using pregreplace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
//CODE
$message = preg_replace('~<pre(.*?)>(.*?)</pre>~si', '[CODE]\\2[/CODE]', $message);
$message = str_replace('Code:', '', $message);
```

This is supposed to replace the links from just being posted as non parsed URLS to inside of a code box like seen below

**EXAMPLE #1**

```
http://linkexample.com
http://linkexample.com
http://linkexample.com
```

Unfortunately it doesnt post it as above it posts the URLS like this....

**EXAMPLE#2**

```
http://linkexample.com http://linkexample.com http://linkexample.com
```

My question is how can I add breaks using preg replace in the code box so the URLS inside the code box look like example 1?

my code at top of this post makes it look like example#2 instead of example#1

I really appreciate ANY help as I am still a rookie with php. thanks

Comment: Are you actually asking how you can turn Example#2 into Example#1?

Comment: yes but I dont know i thought maybe /s but that didnt add the break but yea I know it sounds dumb but im not too good at php

Comment: anyone please? its gotta be something stupid that my lack of php knowledge hindering me

Comment: 1) What do you mean by a "code box"? 2) What is an example `$message`? 3) What exactly do you want the `$message` to become? 4) Where in HTML (and how) do you want to display the output? 5) What exactly are you asking? etc etc. You might want to refactor/rewrite your question.

Comment: exactly as the post says the php preg replace code shows my example#2.I am trying to figure out how to add to my code to make it so each url inside of the bbcode "code" box is on a seperate line instead of all the URLS on the same line.

Comment: here to be more exact I am using my RSS feeds on my site to post articles on my forum. When it posts links it posts them all on the same line instead of each URL on seperate lines. Is there a way to edit my code in the beginning of my first post to make it do this?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting any comments to clarify your intent.

Answer (score 0):

Add breaks: use \n for newline.
It works with your `<pre>` tag.